# Constructing deterministic finite automaton equal to a nondeterministic automaton

Tags: automata, finite-automata, deterministic, automaton

I'm having trouble going through the steps to convert a nondeterministic automaton to a deterministic finite automaton. Below is the problem in question, where I need to construct a deterministic finite automaton equal to the nondeterministic automaton shown. Any help with the steps to solve these sorts of problems, as well as this problem in particular, would be greatly appreciated.

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5ZIl.png)

Here's the NFA's transition table:

```
 Q | s | Q'
===|===|===
q0 | a | q0
q0 | b | q0
q0 | b | q2
q0 | - | q1
q1 | b | q2
q1 | b | q4
q2 | a | q3
q3 | - | q4
q4 | a | q3
```

q3 and q4 are accepting, and q0 is the initial state. The - in the `s` column indicates an episilon/lambda-transition.

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to Stackoverflow. The goal is to have for each state only one transition per event to another state. This means you got to introduce other new states as described here to achieve that goal: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/automata_theory/ndfa_to_dfa_conversion.htm

Comment: Looks like homework...

Answer (score 0):

The set Q of states is {q0, q1, q2, q3, q4}. The states of your equivalent DFA will be drawn from the set of all subsets of states from the NFA, of which there are `2^5 = 32`. Some of these may be unreachable, so we can introduce only the ones we actually reach.

The initial state in the DFA will be the subset of states of the NFA containing q0 along with any states reachable from q0 by traversing only epsilon/lambda transitions. Here, the initial state of the DFA is {q0,q1} since q0 is the initial state of the NFA and q1 is reachable from q0 by traversing only (exactly one) epsilon/lambda transition.

Now we need transitions leaving the state {q0,q1} for each symbol in the alphabet: a and b. The state which {q0,q1} transitions to upon input a is the subset of all states containing only those states reachable from q0 or q1 in the NFA by consuming exactly one a and traversing arbitrarily many epsilon/lambda transitions. The symbol a causes the NFA to transition to q0 if already in q0, and q1 is reachable from q0 by traversing an epsilon/lambda transition; so q0 and q1 will be in the subset to which this next state corresponds. Because q1 does not transition on a in the NFA, this state adds nothing: {q0,q1} transitions to {q0,q1} on input a. On input b, q0 transitions to itself and q2 in the NFA (and q1 as well, since q1 is reachable from q0 by an epsilon/lambda transition). In the NFA, q1 transitions to q4 and q2 in the NFA, so these states are also in the subset to which our state corresponds. Therefore, {q0,q1} transitions to {q0,q1,q2,q4} on input b.

The only state we have encountered for which we lack transitions is {q0,q1,q2,q4}. On input b, we are able to reach each of these states from some other one (q1 by taking the epsilon/lambda transition after transitioning to q0 from q0); but q3 cannot be so reached. Thus, {q0,q1,q2,q4} transitions to itself on input b. On input a, we can reach q0 (hence q1) from q0; nothing from q1; and q3 (hence q4 by the epsilon/lambda transition) from either q2 or q4. Therefore, {q0,q1,q2,q4} transitions to {q0,q1,q3,q4} on input a.

The only state we have encountered for which we lack transitions is {q0,q1,q3,q4}. On input a, verify that we reach the same state {q0,q1,q3,q4}. On input b, verify that we reach the state {q0,q1,q2,q4}.

There are no states for which we lack transitions. We can now enumerate the states, giving them shorter names: {q0,q1} is A; {q0,q1,q2,q4} is B; {q0,q1,q3,q4} is C. Now, the transition table is as follows:

```
 Q | s | Q'
===|===|===
 A   a   A
 A   b   B
 B   a   C
 B   b   B
 C   a   C
 C   b   B
```

The accepting states will be any of our states which correspond to subsets containing states of the NFA which were accepting in the NFA: either q3 or q4. Both states B and C contain state q4, which is accepting in the NFA; so B and C are accepting. The language is the language of all strings which contain at least one b. To see that this is the correct language, consider the NFA.

- any string with at least one b must have a last occurrence of b, after which the string contains nothing but a (or nothing at all), if the string ends with b.
- any string can be consumed up to this point by looping on state q0 in the NFA
- then, the epsilon/lambda transition can be taken to q1
- then, the last b in the string can be consumed to transition to q4
- from that point, all remaining a (if any) can be consumed
- at least one b must be consumed to reach q4 from q1 or to reach q2 to get to q3.

This DFA is not minimal there is a two-state DFA for this language:

```
 Q | s | Q'
===|===|===
 X | a | X
 X | b | Y
 Y | a | Y
 Y | b | Y
```

If X is the initial state and Y the accepting state, this accepts the same language.